# Javascript Regex Function to Determine Whether String Contains Phone Number

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I am tasked with writing a JS function that returns true if a sting contains a phone number in the following formats: XXXXXXXXXX, XXX-XXX-XXXX, XXX XXX XXXX, (XXX) XXX-XXXX, and (XXX)XXX-XXXX.

I have this so far:

```
function containsPhone(input) {
const regex = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
return regex.test(input)
}
```

This only works if the string only contains a phone number but I need it to ignore other things in the string. For example, I need it to work for

> "The phone number is (666) 666-6666"

and not just

> "(666) 666-6666"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the start and end line anchors and you are good to go.

`\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/15)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at the whitespaces, then remove any unwanted symbols from each value using a helper function with `remove()`. Then run each value through a number of conditionals that checks the iterated values adjacent siblings within the string to rebuild your values and run through the helper regex function returning the value of ***output***

```js
const str = [
  'The phone number is not numbers XXX XXX-XXXX.',
  'The phone number is (555) 555-5555,',
  'The phone number is 555-555-5555;',
  'The phone number is 555 555 5555:',
  'The phone number is (555) 555-5555. ',
  'The phone number is (555)555-5555!',
  'The phone number is wrong format(555) e55-5555.'
]

const containsPhone = (input) => {
  const regex = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
  return regex.test(input)
}

const re = (string) => {
  return string.replace(/[.,:;{}*&%$#@!]/, '')
}

const check = (str) => {
  // set initial output to false
  let output = false;
  // initialize phone
  let phone;
  // split the string at white space
  const strings = str.split(' ')
  // run each value through forEach loop
  strings.forEach((val, i) => {
    // run val through helper replace function
    // to remove unwanted symbols from value
    val = re(val)
   
    // if the regex function does not return true &&
    // the value matches 3 numbers surrounded by () => (XXX)
    if (val.match(/^[(][0-9]{3}[)]/) && !containsPhone(val)) {
      // set the phone variable 
      // concat the val and its next value (XXX) XXX-XXXX
      // again removing any unwated following symbols re()
      phone = `${val}${re(strings[i+1])}`
    }
    // now we need to handle XXX XXX XXXX
    // just check values adjacent values to match number    
    if (strings[i + 1] !== undefined && strings[i + 1].match(/[0-9]+/) && val.match(/[0-9]+/) && strings[i - 1].match(/[0-9]+/)) {
      phone = re(`${strings[i - 1]} ${strings[i]} ${strings[i + 1]}`)
    }
    // check our two potential values using the regex function
    if (containsPhone(val) || containsPhone(phone)) {
      output = true
    }
  })
  // return the output
  return output;
}

str.forEach((str, i) => {
  console.log('str ' + Number(i + 1) + ': ' + check(str))
})
```